# Is there any reasonable use for String.ToString?

Tags: c#, string, object, clone, tostring

I just saw this

```
string response = GetResponse();
return response.ToString();
```

Is there any reasonable explanation for using the `ToString()` method?

Comment: no. `string.ToString()` is a no-op (`return this`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That does nothing, from ILSpy:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this;
}
```

But maybe he wants to force a `NullReferenceException`, although that would [**not be best-practise**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/07/11/180315.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

No, there isn't.
The only reason why it is available is, because it comes from Object. (And String inherits from Object)

Comment: Well, string _does_ provide its own implementation; it isn't _just_ there from `object`.

Comment: String.toString(): This object (which is already a string!) is itself returned. <br/>
Object.toString(): The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of<br/>

Taken from: http://docs.oracle.com

Comment: That's my point (although I'm not sure where Oracle and `@hashcode` comes into it).

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. There is no point of converting string in to string again. I think correct code must be as follows:

```
WebResponse response = GetResponse();
return response.ToString();
```

GetResponse() returns WebResponse object.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the marked answer is correct but I'd like to introduce the idea of polymorphism in to the answer here. There is reason to use string.ToString, it would just be indirect.

Consider the following scenario:

```
string s = "my groovy string";
object o = s; //This or something like this could happen for many reasons but this is an example so don't analyze this simplicity. 
Console.Write( o.ToString() ); //We are technically calling string.ToString() leading to the code in Tim's answer where we return this.
```

Aside from the fact that `ToString` is defined on `Object`, this is why `string.ToString` returns itself and **this is reasonable (albeit, round about) use** to get back to the core question.